# In django, is it a bad practice to retrieve database records with slug fields loaded by fixtures?

Tags: django, enums, slug, django-fixtures

I am working on a code base where the original developer created a `ProductType model` with several rows in the database representing a few product types. Throughout the code, there are statements like `ProductType.objects.get(slug='foo_product_type')`. These statements will cause a hard crash if fixtures haven't loaded the `ProductType` record with `slug = 'foo_product_type'`. What is the best practice to define the `ProductType` with slug `'foo_product_type'`? It seems like python code shouldn't depend on fixtures being loaded, but I really can't think of another solution. It feels like a bad practice for your server logic to depend on certain database fields, but im not sure I can think of another method.

I have worked with using `choices=` on the model definition, but that seems to be more for data integrity as opposed to loading a record with details like `price` so that doesn't help me. I currently load fixtures after migrating a new database, and that works, but I'm curious if anyone has a better solution.

```
if ProductType.objects.get(slug='foo_product_type'):
```

when `ProductType` with slug `'foo_product_type'` doesn't exist.

When the fixture is loaded, the object is grabbed for use in code. When record is missing, app crashes.

Comment: The above will not work, since `.get(..)` raises an error in case the record does not exist.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, that is correct. I am looking for another approach. Would a django-enum be appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

You should use *try-except*:

```
try:
   product_type = ProductType.objects.get(slug='foo_product_type')
   ...
except ProductType.DoesNotExist:
   # handle exception here
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Along those lines, there is also get_or_create() https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create. However, I am more looking for a more general solution.